# Name is not displayed in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode6.3

I am trying to do an example on https://github.com/singhson/Expandable-Collapsable-TableView where a storyboard is used. I am trying to do it using xib files. What changes should I make in cellForRowAtIndexPath so that I can get the desired output? I tried something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *Title= [[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];

    [self createCellWithTitle:Title image:[[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image name" ] indexPath:indexPath];
//    return [self createCellWithTitle:Title image:[[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image name"] indexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}

- (UITableViewCell*)createCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image  indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ExpandableTableViewCell* cell = [self.menuTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
    cell.lblTitle.text = title;
    cell.lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];
    cell.indentationWidth = 25;

    float indentPoints = cell.indentationLevel * cell.indentationWidth;

    cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,cell.contentView.frame.origin.y,cell.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,cell.contentView.frame.size.height);

    NSDictionary *d1=[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

    if([d1 valueForKey:@"SubItems"])
    {
        cell.btnExpand.alpha = 1.0;
        [cell.btnExpand addTarget:self action:@selector(showSubItems:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.btnExpand.alpha = 0.0;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Now I am getting the table which can be expanded or collapsed but I it doesn't show the name in table view. What other changes should I make for it to work? Please help.

Comment: Could you show the method:  ´createCellWithTitle´?

Comment: Also, NSString *Title  should not start with uppercase

Comment: When you say "it doesn't show the name in table view" you mean that the title of every cell is not showed? or the title of every subcell?

Comment: Title of every cell and subcell are not shown

Comment: I checked my code again my lblTitle in createCellWithTitle is nil but I am getting value of title. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: And cell is nil? 
Are you registering ExpandableTableViewCell using  ´registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:´ in viewDidLoad?
If the cell is not nil and you registered correctly ExpandableTableViewCell, im pretty sure lblTitle is not linked with the nib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions:

- Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` (to be noticed in case you did´t register the class) instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` because the last one doesn´t crash if you didn't register a class or nib for the identifier, only returns nil.
- Ensure you linked correctly " lblTitle" of your ExpandableTableViewCell class with the xib in the interface builder.
- Check  in this instruction : cell.lblTitle.text = title;  if the title is nil or even if your lblTitle is nil.
- Check if lblTitle is out of bounds (you are changing the contentView in this line:     cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,cell.contentView.frame.origin.y,cell.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,cell.contentView.frame.size.height);)
- Are you registering ExpandableTableViewCell using ´registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:´ in viewDidLoad? 
  Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked the links and used dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath. When I put the debugger and run it I get all the names correctly but it is not getting displayed. Is there anything else that I can check?

Comment: Do you have lblTitle linked with your nib file? Check if its nil.

Comment: Sure I can send it to you

Comment: Can I get your email Id?

Comment: Cant access mail now. I will send it to you as soon as possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76496/discussion-between-itaws-and-javier-flores-font).